# Ordenar de menor a mayor el precio de los ingredientes

Tags: c#

Ayuda, tengo este codigo y necesito que me ordene el costo de los ingredientes que introduzco de MENOR A MAYOR. Ayudenme por favor, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NOMBRE DE LA RECETA");
            string Receta = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("NUMERO DE INGREDIENTES");
            int Cantidad = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("TIEMPO DE PREPARACION");
            String Tiempo = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("");

            String[] Ingrediente = new string[Cantidad];
            int[] Precio = new int[Cantidad];
            int Suma = 0;
            int x;
            string ingre;

            for (int r = 0; r < Cantidad; r++)
            {
                Console.Write("Ingrediente " + (r + 1) + ":");
                string ing = Console.ReadLine();
                Ingrediente[r] = ing;

                Console.Write("TECLEA EL PRECIO ");
                int pe = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Precio[r] = pe;
                Suma = Suma + pe;
                Console.WriteLine("");

            }
            //Metodo burbuja

            for (int Cuenta = 0; Cuenta < Precio.Length; Cuenta++)
            {
                for (int Acumula = 0; Acumula < Precio.Length - 1; Acumula++)
                {


                    if (Precio[Cuenta] < Precio[Acumula])
                    {
                        //precio
                        x = Precio[Cuenta];
                        Precio[Cuenta] = Precio[Acumula];
                        Precio[Cuenta] = x;
                        //ingredientes
                        ingre = Ingrediente[Cuenta];
                        Ingrediente[Cuenta] = Ingrediente[Acumula];
                        Ingrediente[Acumula] = ingre;
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("RECETA DESEADA ES: " + Receta);
            Console.WriteLine("NUMERO DE INGREDIENTES : " + Cantidad);
            Console.WriteLine("TIEMPO DE PREPARACION ES : " + " " + Tiempo);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("INGREDIENTES" + " " + " PRECIO");
            for (int i = 0; i < Precio.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine(Ingrediente[i] + " " + Precio[i]);

            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("COSTO DE LA RECETA: " + Suma);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Dado que tienes `Ingrediente` y `Precio` por separado, lo primero que necesitarás para ordenar ambos es juntarlos, te aconsejo usar [Zip](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var ingredientes = Enumerable.Zip(Precio, Ingrediente, (precio, ingrediente) => new { p = precio, i = ingrediente });
```

Pero ya que estamos, podemos ordenar en la misma instrucción:

```
var ingredientes = Enumerable.Zip(Precio, Ingrediente, (precio, ingrediente) => new { p = precio, i = ingrediente })
                             .OrderBy(item => item.p);
```

Estando ya<sup>1</sup> ordenados, puedes mostrarlos:

```
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine($"RECETA DESEADA ES: {Receta}");
Console.WriteLine($"NUMERO DE INGREDIENTES: {Cantidad}");
Console.WriteLine($"TIEMPO DE PREPARACION ES: {Tiempo}");
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("INGREDIENTES  PRECIO");

foreach (var ingrediente in ingredientes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine($"{ingrediente.i} {ingrediente.p}");

}

Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("COSTO DE LA RECETA: " + Precio.Aggregate(0, (a, b) => a + b));
Console.ReadKey();
```

He usado [cadenas interpoladas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), deberías probarlas.

---

1. En realidad aún no están ordenados los valores. Las secuencias [LinQ](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) se [evalúan de manera perezosa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluaci%C3%B3n_perezosa).